# Is Deja Dup compatible with Dropbox?

Tags: deja-dup

If it is, how do I do it? I'm using Deja Dup 14.2 on Lucid.

Comment: Why are you asking this question? If you want dropbox, why don't you simply install dropbox? Also Lucid is no longer supported. It is recommended to upgrade to 12.04 LTS or 12.10 to make sure your system is secure.

Comment: @To Do: How is Lucid no longer supported? Even assuming Desktop packages (which seems likely here) there will still be support until April 2013.

Comment: Yes you're right, it is actually supported until april 2013. Sorry mate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

There is nothing in Déjà Dup which makes it specifically aware of Dropbox. On the other hand, Déjà Dup can be pointed to a local path, so there is always the option of running your backups towards a path within the Dropbox folder.

As always will should test that you actually can restore, preferably from another computer connected to the same Dropbox, in case the Dropbox sync somehow screws up the backup directory. Not that it should, but you should test and verify nevertheless.